# python performance - list of tuples or dictionary for relationships?

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary, tuples

I want to define a simple replace dictionary, that will be iterated through to clean up a string. For example, to clean up an address, which is better practice (performance, style, etc)?

a)

```
dictionary = {'North': 'N', 'South': 'S', 'East': 'E', 'West': 'W'}
address = 'North South East West'
for key in dictionary:
    address = address.replace(key, dictionary[key])
```

or b)

```
tuple_list = [('North', 'N'), ('South', 'S'), ('East', 'E'), ('West', 'W')]
address = 'North South East West'
for tuple in tuple_list:
    address = address.replace(tuple[0], tuple[1])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Find out yourself with the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Comment: If this is your only use for the data structure, it is more logically expressed as a list of pairs (tuples) because that is how you use it.  Your second example could be better written as `for s, repl in tuple_list: address = address.replace(s, repl)`.

Comment: There are several good answers here, for a very valuable question.  But with the proven marginal difference, and the O(1) lookup regardless, I'd recommend to consider two other issues: (1) Will you use it in other circumstances, too?  Eg, will you be looking up by key ever? (2) And probably more importantly, what's easier for you and your team to read?  What will make obvious sense to you 3 - 9 months later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just iterating over it, you would use a list.

For looking up keys, use a dict.

Not necessarily slower in the first instance, just that it is not what a dict is intended for.

Looking up by key will be considerably faster (than trying to linearly find an element) if you use a dict, and therefore if you are going to use the collection for that purpose, use one. Otherwise do not.

In your case you are not finding "North" "South" "East" and "West" in your dictionary, you are doing the converse - finding them in your "address" string.

Your fastest algorithm might be to tokenise (split) your address string, run through each element and look up in the dict to see if it should be replaced, and then rejoin.

Not only will it be more efficient but it would avoid clbuttic replaces, unless you want those of course.

Comment: `clbuttic` is a little too slangy.

Comment: I like this answer - I'll test for performance later, but this seems super cool (reasonable that it's the faster algorithm). +1 for the laugh induced by looking up clbuttic

Comment: For those who didn't look it up or know what clbuttic means, it is the result of a "find and replace" changing the word 'ass' with 'butt' but forgetting that the sequence 'ass' sometimes appears in the middle of words like 'classic'.

Answer (score 4):

There is not going to be much of a speed difference between the two; you are iterating over two sequences, and only the exact datatype of those structures differs.

Your `dictionary` loop could be ever so slightly more efficient by using the `.iteritems()` method:

```
dictionary = {'North': 'N', 'South': 'S', 'East': 'E', 'West': 'W'}
address = 'North South East West'
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
    address = address.replace(key, value)
```

Since `.iteritems()` gives you a iterable of `(key, value)` pairs this method is exactly the same as using a tuple.

Using the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), you can see there is no real difference between the two methods:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def dictionary(address, d={'North': 'N', 'South': 'S', 'East': 'E', 'West': 'W'}):
...     for s, repl in d.iteritems():
...         address = address.replace(s, repl)
... 
>>> def tuples(address, t=[('North', 'N'), ('South', 'S'), ('East', 'E'), ('West', 'W')]):
...     for s, repl in t:
...         address = address.replace(s, repl)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit("test('North South East West')", 'from __main__ import dictionary as test')
2.5873939990997314
>>> timeit.timeit("test('North South East West')", 'from __main__ import tuples as test')
2.5879111289978027
```

Comment: Would hashing of the keys to find the respective pairs be slightly more costly than plain array indexing of a list of tuples?

Comment: @heltonbiker: looping over a dictionary doesn't use hashing, it's a plain indexing of the underlying array structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
%%timeit
dictionary = {'North': 'N', 'South': 'S', 'East': 'E', 'West': 'W'}
address = 'North South East West'
for key in dictionary:
    address = address.replace(key, dictionary[key])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 us per loop

%%timeit
tuple_list = [('North', 'N'), ('South', 'S'), ('East', 'E'), ('West', 'W')]
address = 'North South East West'
for tuple in tuple_list:
    address = address.replace(tuple[0], tuple[1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 us per loop
```

Like Martijn said, there's effectively no difference.

Comment: There's 10 times loops amount difference:
first 1 000 000
second 100 000

Comment: Doesn't really matter. The timeit module uses some simple heuristics to decide the number of loops to run but it's an average per loop. Won't make much difference.

Comment: Do I get it right, that dictionary will give benefit only with key based search?
I mean, if we use index based operation or choose random item from dictionary, it will have same performance as list?

Comment: Not the same but marginal difference.  When you iterate over a dictionary, it already has an internal array of keys, so you are just iterating over that array and returning the objects pointed to by those keys.  Looking up the values will be a little slower but it's still ~O(1).